# Why does a TextArea with NoWrap always cause an "anchor loop detected" warning?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent, qt5.5

Why is a `TextArea` with

```
wrapMode: TextEdit.NoWrap
```

always causing

> file:///C:/Qt/5.5/mingw492_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ScrollView.qml:340:13: QML Item: Possible anchor loop detected on fill.

when I run it?

I am running Qt 5.5 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, and compiling with MinGW.

Here is my QML code `test.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "test window"
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true

    TextArea {
        wrapMode: TextEdit.NoWrap
    }
}
```

Here is my C++ code `main.c`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/test.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Even if I add `anchors.fill: parent` to the `TextArea`, I still get the warnings.

As a second part of this question, is this warning something I should be worried about, or is it something I can safely ignore?

Comment: Obviously this question is not related to `C++`, please, next time don't put `c++` tag on questions like this. In this question you may even remove your `main.c` because it does nothing but loads your QML and the question is about `qml`-behaviour.

Comment: I'm new to Qt and didn't know if the way of launching the qml file might affect it in some way I don't understand. Next time I will remember to limit the information I give.

Comment: In this case your `c++` is not needed. Also, your question requires an answer about `QML` but not `c++`. I'd suggest you to remove your `c++` code snippet, information about OS and compiler because it is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Your TextArea doesn't have a size specified, so it's not clear what the expected behavior would be in this situation.  What happens if you either assign dimensions or anchors to the TextArea?

Comment: @MrEricSir Originally I had some more things like a button above it, and then i anchored it to the left, right, and bottom of the parent, and the top of the text box was anchored to the bottom of the button, but I still got that error. So for the example, I tried removing anything unnecessary. If ony my example I add `anchors.fill: parent` to the TextArea, it still gives the error.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that the warning being printed is a bug.. it probably shouldn't happen.

Comment: It even gets worse if you add text and exceed the current viewport (with or without `width`/`height` set). Removing the offending row solves the problem. Uhm, I agree with @Mitch about that. I wish you long life and good health 'cos you found a bug! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug from Qt, you can ignore it.
When created, `TextArea` have a `width != 0`, even if it's empty. When you enter a text that have an `implicitWidth` smaller then the (default) `width` of the `TextArea`, you will get this warning.

A **workaround** is to assign the `wrapMode` property in the `Component.onCompleted` handler:

```
Component.onCompleted: wrapMode = TextEdit.NoWrap
```

Comment: I think it's an issue deeper than a `width` issue (even if setting/not setting `width` can greatly effect the warning). Anyhow, filed a bug - [QTBUG-47167](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47167).